# Join multiple strings into one single string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have a loop that is generating a string

```
function jsonResponse(response)
{
    var singleString = a + "," + b + "," + c + "|";
}
```

with `console.log(singleString);`

I see them all generated :

```
a1,b1,c1|
a2,b2,c2|
a3,b3,c3|
```

But how can I create a new variable `allStrings` that will concatenate all of these into one string?  The loop is part of an ajax response that is looping through xml nodes to retrieve the data for those variables.  I guess I need to make them part of an array and then join them back together for one big string?

To further clarify what I am trying to achieve is something like :

```
  var allStrings = singleString[0] + singleString[1] + singleString[2] ;

    a1,b1,c1|a2,b2,c2|a3,b3,c3|
```

To better explain the loop it looks like this :

```
$j.ajax({
    type: "GET",

    url: "test.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success:   function  parseXml(data)
    {
        $j('.loader').fadeOut();
        itemQueue = $j(data).find("ITEM").map( function ()
            {
                return {
                        date: $j("LAST_SCAN" , this).text(),
                        type : $j("PRODUCT_TYPE", this).text(),
                        cat : $j("CLASS_NAME", this).text(),
                        };  
            }).get();
            getNextItem();  

        }
    });

function getNextItem()
    {    
        var item = itemQueue[0];
        var singleString = item.date+ "," + item.type +  "," + item.cat + "\n";
        console.log( singleString );

        $j.ajax({
            url: s7query,
            dataType: 'jsonp'
        });
      }

function s7jsonResponse(response)
{
    var item = itemQueue.shift();
    if (itemQueue.length)
    {
        getNextItem();  
    }
    // run other processes when finished with checks
    if (!itemQueue.length)
    {   
        // alert ("ALL DONE");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 19):

You can use [`Array.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to convert an array to a string.

Example:

```
var arr = ['a1', 'b1', 'c1'];
console.log(arr.join(',')); // 'a1,b1,c1'
```

Comment: I updated my question, perhaps it was confusing.  This is not what I am trying to achieve.  I have a single variable name that will be replaced for every loop.  I wanted to grab all of those strings and then combine all of them into one.

Comment: @Zac: Use the `+=` operator?  `allStrings += singleString;`

Comment: Thaks I was looking for another solution but while randomly searching I got this answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can get rid if that loop and use:

```
array.join(',')
```

Where `array` is the array you want to turn in to a string separated by commas.

To join the strings together you just need to construct a string concatenation:

```
allStrings.concat(string1, string2, ..., stringX)
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're making separate XHRs for independent XML nodes, in which case you may want to reconsider your approach. If possible, I would iterate over the XML nodes in their entirety and gather all necessary request data. Then you can make a single XHR (cutting down on HTTP connections, which is good!) and get a single response that could contain the entirety of the response (i.e. allStrings). It should be easier on your server and make a noticable difference on the client side in pretty much all situations.

Comment: Yes you are correct.  I had to do it this way though.. long story but it needs to run a check for data from one node over and over against a second request.